# Implementation of Array.length in OCaml

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, shared-libraries, ocaml

I want to understand how [Array.length](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Array.html) is implemented. I managed to write it with `Array.fold_left`:

```
let length a = Array.fold_left (fun x _ -> x + 1) 0 a
```

However in the [standard library](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/array.ml), `fold_left` uses `length` so that can't be it. For `length` there is just this line in the stdlib which I don't understand:

```
external length : 'a array -> int = "%array_length"
```

How can I write `length` without using`fold_left`?

**EDIT:**

I tried to do it with pattern matching, however it is not exhaustive, how can I make the matching more precise? (The aim is to remove the last element and return i+1 when only one element is left)

```
let length a = 
         let rec aux arr i = 
         match arr with
           | [|h|] -> i+1
           | [|h;t|] -> aux [|h|] (i+1)
        in aux a 0;;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to use lists instead of arrays for your exercise?

Answer (score 4):

The array type is a primitive type, like the `int` type.
The implementation of many primitives functions on those primitive type is done with either C functions or compiler primitives.

The `Array.length` function belongs to the compiler primitive category and it is defined in the standard library by:

```
external length : 'a array -> int = "%array_length"
```

Here, this declaration bind the value `length` to the compiler primitive `%array_length` (compiler primitive names start with a `%` symbol) with type `'a array -> int`. The compiler translates such compiler primitive to a lower level implementation during the translation process from the source code to either native code or bytecode.

In other words, you cannot reimplement `Array.length` or the array type in general in an efficient way yourself because this type is a basic building block defined by the compiler itself.

Answer (score 3):

> For `length` there is just this line in the stdlib which I don't understand:

The `external` keyword indicates that this function is implemented in C, and `"%array_length"` is the C symbol naming this function. The OCaml runtime is implemented in C and some types, like arrays, are built-in (also called primitives).

See for example *Implementing primitives* in [Chapter 20: Interfacing C with OCaml](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/intfc.html)

> I tried to do it with pattern matching, however it is not exhaustive, how can I make the matching more precise

Note that OCaml tells you which pattern is not matched:

```
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
[|  |]
```

So you have to account for empty vectors as well.

Comment: The actual implementation of `%array_length` is here: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/a225f3bd86cdbbbf666bae856d04e0eea1086398/runtime/array.c#L32-L40. For non-float arrays it simply gets the size of the block, which is just a field stored alongside the block's contents.

Comment: No, this is not the implementation of `%array_length`, `%array_length` is a compiler primitive, which is implemented by the compiler itself, and the function caml_array_length is not used at all in the implementation.

Comment: Apologies. I'm curious what this IS used for then, and if the actual implementation differs from it in any meaningful way (other than being inlined, most likely).

Comment: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/asmcomp/cmm_helpers.ml#L2153 for the native version and https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/runtime/interp.c#L866 for the bytecode interpreter.